# Should you add any notes to sell copies of a 3rd party MIT licenced software?

Tags: mit, license-notice

The MIT licence says

> publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software

but still to do that should you add notes or anything above or below in the licence or readme files to make it clear your not affiliated with the creators of the original work.

Should I add clarification above the original notice to say my changes I'm also putting under MIT licence and I'm not affiliated with the previous creators?

It just sounds like if I don't add any clarification it may seem like I'm distributing it on behalf of the original creators which I don't want.

Minor modifications by myself also under the MIT licence.
As of writing this, I am not nor have ever been affiliated with the creators of the original work.

The original copyright notice in licence:

> The MIT License
>
> Copyright (c)
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
>   in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
>   to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
>   copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
>   furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
>   IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
>   AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
>   OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
>   SOFTWARE.

Answer (score 2):

If you are selling an unmodified copy of the software, adding yourself to the license text is the wrong thing to do.

You are selling access to a copy of the software, not a licensing permission.  Without substantial modifications, you don't own copyright to the software.  Adding your name to the license text would be misleading, and you are not in a position to sue for copyright infringement either.

That doesn't mean that you cannot sell a copy of the software for pricing and conditions of your liking and sue over "breach of contract" when the conditions aren't kept.  But suing for "breach of copyright" is not in your toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can if you want but the licence doesn't require it.